# Bootstrap 4 column ordering with WHMCS Template

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, whmcs

So, I'm rebuilding my website's theme which is powered by WHMCS. I'm doing it using bootstrap 4. Using BS4, I'm trying to figure out how to do the column ordering in the client area (just like the default "six" template does (which uses BS3)), but not having much luck. It should go something like this - On desktop view the Primary and Secondary navs should sit on the left side, with the main content to the right, and on mobile view the primary nav shrinks and sits above the content, with the secondary nav after the content:

Desktop View:

```
PN | MC
SN |
```

Mobile View:

```
PN
MC
SN
```

Here is the basic layout html:

```
<div class="container">
    <main class="row">
        <aside class="col-sm-3">
            BS4 Card containing Primary Navigation
        </aside>
        <article class="col-sm-9">
            Main client area content
        </article>
        <aside class="col-sm-3">
            BS4 Card containing Secondary Nav
        </aside>
    </main>
</div>
```

I cannot figure out how to get the secondary nav to sit on the left below the primary nav when in desktop view, rather it's sitting to the left below the main content. In BS3, this was done simply by using a left float, but since BS4 uses flex-boxes, that no longer works.

**Edit:**
Here are some fiddles so you can see whats happening:

- [BS4 Version - Not working](https://www.bootply.com/KjqVTQsjb2)
- [BS3 Version - Old way that works perfectly](https://www.bootply.com/W35kD0rGdc)

Note: Removed images because the fiddles show exactly the same thing.

Comment: Hi. Can you post your code here through fiddle or otherwise? I may have a solution, but need to check if it works with your particular use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution: 
Add a class 'adjust' (or any name you wish) to the third column.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                nav
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque temporibus dolorum ea natus nam labore delectus vel, voluptatibus libero eligendi fuga optio! Nisi nemo architecto est, tenetur hic nesciunt distinctio totam repellat necessitatibus. Explicabo nam illum incidunt iusto recusandae nobis eos inventore dolore, suscipit cum earum numquam alias eveniet voluptatem!
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 adjust">
                nav2
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .adjust{
   position:relative;
   bottom: 100px; /* whatever adjustment you wish */

 }

 @media(max-width:768px){
 .adjust{
  position:relative;
  top: 100px; /* whatever adjustment required to push it back down */
  }

 }
```

Comment: I think I can see what your trying to do here, but I don't think this would work because the adjustment would need to know the sizes of the columns, but each nav section and the content itself will change size depending on the page being viewed.

Answer (score 0):

You have been using bootstrap grid incorrectly. Sum of all col should be 12.
I have posted the working code that you need:

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <main class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-ms-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
        <div class="row">
        <aside class="col">
            BS4 Card containing Primary Navigation
        </aside>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <aside class="col">
            BS4 Card containing Secondary Nav
        </aside>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-ms-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
        <article class="col">
            Main client area content
        </article>
        </d
```

For the mobile view, add a media query which makes secondary nav `position:fixed`.

Comment: On phone screens, this will push the main client area content all the way down, and the second navbar will be sandwiched between the two columns. Consider using 'order' css rule here to change the order on smaller screens.

Comment: @RohanMayya Thanks for the comment. But do look at the edit that i have made. It will fix the problem at hand. It is up to Johnno13 to decide how much distance to have from bottom in the media query.

Comment: @RohanMayya you need flex items for 'order' css rule to work. The problem needs to be solved by using current bootstrap code

Comment: @RohanMayya Using order wouldn't be the answer because on mobile screens, the order is already correct.

Comment: @Arex Your example didn't work at all. It doesn't collapse the way I want it to on smaller screens. Note also that I am using the latest version of BS4.

Comment: I have updated the original post to include fiddles of the BS4 version that I'm trying to get working, and the BS3 way of doing it that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution to this. I was hoping to keep the flexbox structure on the elements and position the appropriately using the flexbox, but the following solution works and will do for now.

First, convert the containing `.row` plus the inner `.col-sm-*` items to block level items using BS4's display utilities by adding `.d-lg-block` to all 4 elements.
Next, use the float utilities to pull each column appropriately. In this case, adding `.float-lg-left` to the first and third columns (the navigation columns), and `.float-lg-right` to the middle column (the main content).

Here's a fiddle of it working in BS4: https://www.bootply.com/0TrQZNXF1S